# Downloading JSON file, but parsing displays unreadable characters

Tags: c#, json, character-encoding

I'm trying to download a JSON file from a ParseHub API I created for a local website. If I type the URL into the browser, I get the JSON formatted and all.

But when downloading into my C# app, it just displays random, unreadable characters like in the following image:
[Console app displaying the result of downloaded JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zV9v.png)

I tried downloading the page as a string:

```cs
Uri uri = new Uri(url); //url is the link to my API page
HttpClient wc = new HttpClient();

string json = await wc.GetStringAsync(uri);
```

During the debug sessions I see the unreadable characters that are downloaded and saved in the string json.

I tried the URL in "Postman", and it gives me: [Postman Headers tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QA37O.png)

Notice: it says Content-Encoding: gzip.

I think this may be the issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

If it is gzip encoded then you can get the data as a stream instead and read it via a GZipStream

Also ideally you should use WebClient instead of HttpClient. I suspect making that change alone would be sufficient for it to automatically decompress.